# How sizeof works ? Memory map for variable length array of strings

Tags: c, sizeof

```
const char *pointerStr[]=
{
   "BEST123,      ",     // 0x00
   "Best2233,     ",     // 0x01
   "ABCDEFGH,     ",     // 0x02
   "123456,     ",     // 0x03
   "helloworld,     "     // 0x04
};
typedef struct
{
   char value;
   char name[40]; 
}StrInfo;

typedef struct
{
   int regMax;
   StrInfo info[60];   
} structNew;

void main()
{
  int i;
  structNew  pret;
for ( i=0;i<5;i++)
{     
  printf("PointerStr size of %dth %d \n",i,sizeof(pointerStr[i]));
  printf("pret size of %dth %d \n",i,sizeof(pret.info[i].name));
}
}
```

The above program produce the result of

```
PointerStr size of 0th 4 
pret size of 0th 40 
PointerStr size of 1th 4 
pret size of 1th 40 
PointerStr size of 2th 4 
pret size of 2th 40 
PointerStr size of 3th 4 
pret size of 3th 40 
PointerStr size of 4th 4 
pret size of 4th 40
```

If I want to know the size of each and every string in PointerStr then how to find it? Is it possible only using strlen ? do we have some other way ? How this variable length array is stored in memory ?
 The result is becoz that pointerStr is pointer variable and its size is always 4. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: For normal 0-terminated strings, like the ones in `pointerStr`, then `strlen` is what you should use.

Comment: There is no variable length array in your code. All are fixed at compile time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The length of a C string is implicit: it is determined by where the terminating `'\0'` is in the string, so you will need a function like `strlen` to determine the length of a string.

The values 'returned' by `sizeof` are determined by the compiler by looking at the *type* of the data, instead of the data itself.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting the length of the array, but only the size of a pointer for the `char*`, is that `sizeof` is not a function call as it appears, but actually calculated at compile-time (except for variable-length arrays).

Your code exemplifies a key difference between arrays and pointers.  At compile-time, the compiler knows exactly how long your array is (`40`), because it is statically sized.  On the other hand, a `char*` doesn't even necessarily point to a null-terminated string, so it returns the size of the pointer.

The correct way to find the length of the strings is to use `strlen`.  However, note that this will tell you the number of characters before the first null-byte (`\0`).  It will not tell you how much memory is actually allocated (which is what `sizeof` is doing when it returns `40`).

Answer (score 1):

*sizeof* is a compiler thing. It gives the size of data, as seen during compilation. It has nothing to do with dynamic memory allocation at execution time. So `sizeof(char*)` or `sizeof(p)` with a variable declared as `char* p;` is often the size of the word (i.e. 4 on a 32 bits processor, 8 on a 64 bits processor) and has nothing to do with dynamic allocation, or with the actual length of the string when the program is running.

Answer (score 1):

sizeof gives you the size in bytes of the variable passed to it. You are passing an array of pointers (pointing at strings) to sizeof. Arrays in C "decay" into pointers, so what you get is a pointer to the first element in your array of pointers.

And then you correctly get the size of the pointer in bytes (4 bytes = 32 bit address bus).

Because of the "array decay" rule, there is no way you can get the actual memory cell sizes of the string literals through that pointer, for the same reason that you can't get the size of an array through the pointer ptr in this example:

```
char array[10] = "...";
char* ptr = &array;
```

The solution is to either store the arrays in a different manner where you can use the sizeof on the arrays themselves (like a true 2D array), or to store all array sizes in a lookup table:

```
const size_t STRING_SIZES[] =
{
  sizeof("BEST123,      "),
  sizeof("Best2233,     "),
  sizeof("ABCDEFGH,     "),
  sizeof("123456,     "),
  sizeof("helloworld,     ")
};
```